# Return Callback inside Callback Swift

Tags: swift, callback, swift5, completion

I have a SDK integration that returns a response using a completion but I want to create another completion to return the callback response, but I don't know how.

This is my attempt to do that

```
func validatingProcces(completion: ((Any)?)->()) {
    let conekta = Conekta()
    conekta.delegate = self
    conekta.publicKey = "key_KJysdbf6PotS2ut2"
    conekta.collectDevice()
    let card = conekta.card()
    let token = conekta.token()
    
    card!.setNumber(String(cardToSave!.cardNumber), name: cardToSave!.fullName, cvc: String(cardToSave!.cvc), expMonth: String(cardToSave!.month), expYear: String(cardToSave!.year))

    token!.card = card
    
   

    token!.create(success: { (data) -> Void in
        completion(data as Any)
        
    }, andError: { (error) -> Void in
        print(error as Any)
        completion(error as Any)
    })
    
}
```

I have the following error:

> Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completion'

and also:

> 1. Parameter 'completion' is implicitly non-escaping
> 2. Captured here

Ps. You'll find the SDK integration here:
https://github.com/conekta/conekta-ios

Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not sure if this is the problem you're facing, but have you tried `completion: @escaping ((Any)?)->()`?

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code it looks like you could just make a callback like this:

```
completion: @escaping (Any?, Error?) -> ()
```

and pass in the result of the api callback so you can handle it elsewhere like this

```
token!.create(success: { data in
    completion(data, nil)
}, andError: { error in
    print(error as Any)
    completion(nil, error)
})
```

Let me know if this works